# How do I prevent Python / Django from saving variables in memory between page refreshes?

Tags: python, django, memory, middleware

Does Python / Django save variables between page refresh?
Here is my code:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    _images_set = []


@csrf_exempt
def get_products(request):
    item = Item()
    item._images_set.append('Yay')
    return HttpResponse(json_utilities.get_success())
```

Every time I refresh the page, and stop the debugging to inspect item, the `_images_set` grows by 1. I come from the PHP world, where every time a page reloads all the variables are reset. Could someone explain what is going on here? I don't want `_images_set` to just keep growing and growing, how do I tell Python / Django to reset all  variables at each new page load?

Comment: try sending item._images_set as json to your html template and see if its size keeps increasing. Also I don't think you are supposed create models fields with `[ ]`

Comment: You shouldn't try to "prevent" it. Rather, you should rethink your design. What is the point of that class attribute in the first place?